# Getting response with NodeJS request module

Tags: json, node.js, api, amazon-web-services, twitch

I just started using the [twitch kraken api](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/guides/using-the-twitch-api) and I have a few questions.

Whenever I attempt to get a JSON object there is no response. I am attempting to run this function through Amazon AWS Lambda, and don't have access to a console.

In the code below my callback function will always print out "SUCCESS got streamers ERROR". I am pretty certain right now the "ERROR" comes from my initial setting of result.

How come result does not get changed into the proper JSON?

I have used postman and it returns the proper thing with the query and param, and headers:

```
function getJSON(callback){
    var result = "ERROR";
    request.get(url(games[0]),function(error,response,body){
        console.log("requested for url: " + url(games[0]));
        var d = JSON.parse(body);
        result = d.streams[0];//.channel.display_name;
        // for(var i = 0; i < limit; i++){
        //     streamers.push(d.streams[i].channel.display_name)
        // }
        streamers.push(result);
    });
    if (streamers.length < 0){
        callback("ERROR");
    }else{
        callback("SUCCESS got streamers " + result);
    }
}

function url(game){
    return {
        url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/",//twitchlimit,
        qs : {
            'game' : 'overwatch',
            'limit' : 2
        },
        headers: {
            'Client-ID': clientID,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Your ```if ... else``` belongs in the ```request.get``` callback

Comment: Note that a 0 length array of streamers would not necessarily be an error.  If you query for streams of a game where nobody is streaming then you'll get back en empty result set.  You can never have a length of less than 0 in an array.

Comment: yeah the <0 i wasn't thinking lol. I made the error be <= 0; It seems like an async code problem from the other comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your streamers code

```
if (streamers.length < 0){
    callback("ERROR");
}else{
    callback("SUCCESS got streamers " + result);
}
```

should be included in the request callback because currently it's not waiting for the request to finish, it's just carrying on so therefore the value of `result` will not change. Also the array length cannot be less than 0 so it will always go to the else and say "SUCCESS got streamers ERROR"

Comment: this is what I thought after a while too. gonna try it out

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the suggestions. I did have a few oversights and attempted to fix them.
I have implemented you suggestions and it seems to have worked a bit. I ended up putting the json.parse into a try/catch block, and moved the if/else statements inside the getJSON method. However, now I don't get any output.

This is how I am invoking the getJSON method:

```
function handleGameResponse(intent,session,callback){
    //gets the game
    var game = intent.slots.game.value;
    if (!games.includes(game)){
        var speechOutput = "You asked for: " + intent.slots.game.value;
        //var speechOutput = "You asked for: " + games[game] + " That game is currently not an option. These are your current options: " + arrayToString(games)
        var repromptText = "Please ask one from the current options.";
        var header = "Invalid Game";

    }else {
        getJSON(function(data){
            if(data !== "ERROR"){
                var speechOutput = data; //capitalizeFirst(game) + " top three streamers are: " + arrayToString(streamers) + '.';
                var repromptText = "Do you want to hear more about games?";
                var header = capitalizeFirst(game);
            }else{
                var speechOutput = "I'm sorry, something went wrong and I could not get the streamers.";
            }
            //speechOutput = data;
        });
        //speechOutput = games[0] + " games[0], game= " + game; //this executes so the getJSON isn't executing
    }
    var shouldEndSession = false;
    callback(session.attributes,buildSpeechletResponse(header,speechOutput,repromptText,shouldEndSession));
}
```

Does the above execute the same way? As in the shouldEndSession and callback execute before the getJSON has time to give a response?

For ref, this is the getJSON method now:

```
function getJSON(callback){
    var result = "ERROR";
    request.get(url(games[0]),function(error,response,body){
        try{
            var d = JSON.parse(body);
        } catch (err){
            callback("Sorry, something seems to have malfunctioned while getting the streamers");
        }
        result = d.streams[0].channel.display_name;
        // for(var i = 0; i < limit; i++){
        //     streamers.push(d.streams[i].channel.display_name)
        // }
        streamers.push(result);
        if (streamers.length <= 0){
            callback("ERROR");
        }else{
            callback("SUCCESS got streamers " + result);
        }
    });
}
```